# Promise executes then function before previous then execution is completed

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, promise, es6-promise

I'm try to chain a couple of then functions which execute sequentially, but the last .then() is being executed before the previous is done executing and as a result it sends an empty payload. Following is the snippet:

```
router.get("/selectedHotels", function(req, res) {
  let payload = [];
  return collectionRef
    .where("isOwner", "==", true)
    .get() //fetches owners
    .then(snapshot => {
      snapshot.forEach(user => {
        console.log("User", user);
        collectionRef
          .doc(user.id)
          .collection("venues")
          .get() // fetches hotels from owners
          .then(snapshot => {
            snapshot.forEach(doc => {
              if (
                doc.data().location.long == req.query.long &&
                doc.data().location.lat == req.query.lat
              ) {
                console.log(doc.id, "=>", doc.data());
                payload.push({
                  id: doc.id,
                  data: doc.data()
                });
              }
            });
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log("No hotels of this user", err);
          });
      });
    })
    .then(() => {
      console.log("Payload", payload);
      response(res, 200, "Okay", payload, "Selected hotels");
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log("Error getting documents", err);
      response(res, 404, "Data not found", null, "No data available");
    });
});
```

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: The inside of your first then doesn't return a Promise, you're iterating through the snapshots and returning nothing.

Comment: why do you need two outer then()s in this situation?

Comment: @nem035: Why the edit?  It was quite readable as it.

Comment: @ScottSauyet I [prettified](https://prettier.io) the code

Comment: @nem035: I don't think that's appropriate when the code is reasonably formatted to begin.  The original formatting didn't match my preference either, but that's not the point.

Comment: @ScottSauyet I didn't do it for personal reasons, the code had inconsistent spacing and formatting so instead of manually fixing each section I figured passing it through a well-known formatter makes more sense.

Comment: @nem035: I don't know if there's a strong convention here, but ISTM that editing for formatting only makes sense when the original is formatted in a confusing manner.  In this particular case, the new placement of the line comments made them much less useful.  This is not meant as a major critique; I just didn't see the reason for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your using firestore so you need to give all documents to map and you also need to return some values to next then. I hope this will help you to solve your problem.

```
router.get('/selectedVenues',function(req,res){
    return collectionRef.where('isOwner', '==', true).get() 
    .then(snapshot => {
        let venues = [];
        snapshot.docs.map(user => {
            venues.push(collectionRef.doc(user.id).collection('venues').get());
        });
        return Promise.all(venues);
    }).then(snapshots => {
        let payload = [];
        snapshots.forEach(venues => {
            venues.docs
                .filter(doc => 
                    doc.data().longitude == req.query.lng && 
                    doc.data().latitude == req.query.lat
                )
                .map(doc => 
                    payload.push({
                        id: doc.id,
                        data: doc.data()
                    })
                ) 
        });
        return payload ;
    }).then(payload => {
        console.log('Payload', payload);
        response(res, 200, "Okay", payload, "Selected hotels");
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log('Error getting documents', err);        
        response(res, 404, 'Data not found', null, 'No data available');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Your main mistake is that you have a non-promise returning function, `forEach`, in the middle of your nested promise chain.

```
router.get('/selectedHotels',function(req,res){ 
  let payload = [];
  return collectionRef.where(...).get()
    .then((snapshot)=>{
        snapshot.forEach(user => {
//      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ this means the outer promise doesn't wait for this iteration to finish
// ...
```

The easiest fix is to map your array of promises, pass them into `Promise.all` and return them:

```
router.get('/selectedHotels',function(req,res){ 
  let payload = [];
  return collectionRef.where(...).get()
    .then((snapshot)=> {
      return Promise.all(snapshot.map(
        // ...
        return collectionRef.doc(user.id).collection('venues').get()
          .then(...)
      ))
```

That being said, nesting promises like this is an anti-pattern. A promise chain allows us to propagate values through the then callbacks so there's no need to nest them.

Instead, you should chain them vertically.

Here's an example of how you can do that:

```
router.get("/selectedHotels", function(req, res) {
  return collectionRef
    .where("isOwner", "==", true)
    .get() //fetches owners
    // portion of the chain that fetches hotels from owners
    // and propagates it further
    .then(snapshot =>
      Promise.all(
        snapshot.map(user =>
          collectionRef
            .doc(user.id)
            .collection("venues")
            .get()
        )
      )
    )
    // this portion of the chain has the hotels
    // it filters them by the req query params
    // then propagates the payload array
    // (no need for global array)
    .then(snapshot =>
      snapshot
        .filter(
          doc =>
            doc.data().location.long == req.query.long &&
            doc.data().location.lat == req.query.lat
        )
        .map(doc => ({ id: doc.id, data: doc.data() }))
    )
    // this part of the chain has the same payload as you intended
    .then(payload => {
      console.log("Payload", payload);
      response(res, 200, "Okay", payload, "Selected hotels");
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log("Error getting documents", err);
      response(res, 404, "Data not found", null, "No data available");
    });
});
```

Comment: for some reason, the map function is not working, 
`Error getting documents TypeError: snapshot.map is not a function
   at collectionRef.where.get.then.snapshot (/srv/routes/api/venue/index.js:24:22)
   at <anonymous>
   at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:228:7)`

Comment: @nem035, I see two mistakes: `.then(snapshot => snapshot.filter(` the argument here should be a matrix: `doc[][]` you'd have to flatten that before you `.filter().map()`. And you got rid of the `.catch(err => { console.log("No hotels of this user", err); });` wich means your promise fails if a single user has no hotels; I'd also extend this catch by a `return []` to properly integrate with the flattening I mentioned

Answer (score 0):

When chaining `.then` with asynchronous work, you need to return the promise you want to resolve before the next `.then` is executed. Something like this :

```
    return Promise.all(snapshot.map(user => {
            console.log("User", user);
            return collectionRef.doc(user.id).collection('venues').get() // fetches hotels from owners
            .then(snapshot => {
                snapshot.forEach((doc)=> {
                        if (doc.data().location.long == req.query.long && doc.data().location.lat == req.query.lat){
                            console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
                            payload.push({
                                id: doc.id,
                                data: doc.data()
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }).catch((err)=>{
                    console.log('No hotels of this user', err);        
                });        
        });
    )
```

You can see it in action in this sample snippet :

```js
function asyncStuff() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('async')
      resolve();
    }, 100)
  });
}

function doStuff() {
  console.log('started');
  asyncStuff()
  .then(() => {
    return Promise.all([0,1,2].map(() => asyncStuff()));
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('second then');
  })
  .then(() => console.log('finished'));
}

doStuff();
```

And see that without the return it gives your initial behaviour :

```js
function asyncStuff() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('async')
      resolve();
    }, 100)
  });
}

function doStuff() {
  console.log('started');
  asyncStuff()
  .then(() => {
    Promise.all([0,1,2].map(() => asyncStuff()));
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('second then');
  })
  .then(() => console.log('finished'));
}

doStuff();
```

Comment: can't we use async-await instead of setTimeout?

Comment: @MuhammadZaidIkhlas `setTimeout` is just here to simulate an asynchronous work. It's just faking a remote request like you do in your example. `async/await` is a way to handle asynchronous work, it can (and hopefully will) replace promises

Comment: @Logar async/await doesn't replace promises. It enhances them. The only thing async/await changes is that it allows us to write code with promises in a synchronous looking manner and use constructs like `try/catch`. It is still completely based on promises. In fact, every `async` function always returns a promise.

Comment: @nem035 I know it's working with a clever use of promises and generators for now (how could it be different since it's part of es2017 spec), but I thought that once we will be able to use it in vanilla, it would be implemented natively and so get rid of the use of the promises. Am I getting something wrong here ?

Comment: And when I say it will replace promises, it's because I can't think of a use case where promises would be more handy than async/await, but I'd love to improve my knowledge on that topic if you want to elaborate

Answer (score 0):

You're not returning a promise from within your first `then`, so there's no way for the code to know that it should wait for an asynchronous result.

```
router.get('/selectedHotels',function(req,res){ 
    let payload = [];
    return collectionRef.where('isOwner', '==', true).get() //fetches owners
    .then((snapshot)=>{
        var userVenuesPromises = [];
        snapshot.forEach(user => {
            userVenuesPromises.push(collectionRef.doc(user.id).collection('venues').get());

        })
        return Promise.all(userVenuesPromises);
    })
    .then((snapshots) => {
        snapshots.forEach((snapshot) => {
            snapshot.forEach((doc)=> {
                if (doc.data().location.long == req.query.long && doc.data().location.lat == req.query.lat){
                    console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
                    payload.push({
                        id: doc.id,
                        data: doc.data()
                    });
                }
            });
        });
        return payload;
    })
    .then((payload) => {
        ...
```

In addition to using `Promise.all()` to ensure all nested loads are done before continuing to the next step, this also removes the nested promise, instead unpacking the values from the snapshots in a an additional step.